# Is there a way to call in a tuple one index at the time using a button (Tkinter)?

Tags: python, loops, tkinter, tuples, counter

I am learning Python using some Youtube videos and reading these threads in StackOverflow but after many hours watching videos and reading I couldn't find the answer of this problem:

I need to set in a variable one element of the tuple at the time using a loop or it could be a simple counter (then i would be able to extract the value from the counter and set it as a guide to call all the following values in the tuple, but all the forms i tried didn't work), every step would be activated by a **button** (tkinter).

The main idea is making a sort of Imageroll and the button would be a "NEXT BUTTON".

I tried so many things, i post this code i found in this website because it isn't so complicate (and kinda works).

````
root = Tk()
root.geometry("200x200")
root.title("My Button Increaser")

rollImagenes=["1.png","2.png","3.png", "4.png", "5.png"]

global counter
counter = 0
def nClick():
    global counter
    counter += 1
    mButton1.config(text = counter)
    

print(counter)

mButton1 = Button(text ="NEXT", command = nClick, fg = "darkgreen", bg = "white")
mButton1.pack()

NUMCLICKS=???

root.mainloop()```
````

Comment: What would you like to do exactly?

Comment: I want to make an Image-roll using every element of the tuple as a variable which later would be used as a reference to build different "constructions". for ex: var=1 --> click in next button --> var=2. After that i could call var to compose for ex the name of the image var=1 = IMG1.png ---> click--> var=2 = IMG2.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a generator expression to yield each element one after the other.

Here, we use a `list` from which we `pop` one element at a time, reinsert it at the other end before yielding it. If the number of elements becomes large, you could use a `collections.deque` data structure as a roundrobin, or better yet, `itertools.cycle`.

```
import tkinter as tk


def _roll(seq):
    while True:
        elt = seq.pop(0)
        seq.append(elt)
        yield elt


def nClick():
    mButton1.config(text=next(roll))


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("200x200")
root.title("My Button Increaser")

rollImagenes = ["1.png", "2.png", "3.png", "4.png", "5.png"]
roll = _roll(rollImagenes)

mButton1 = tk.Button(text="NEXT", command=nClick, fg="darkgreen", bg="white")
mButton1.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick answer AND THE PATIENCE for explaining how it works! that code gets me closer to my project! Definitely i couldn't understand everything but i already have some new concepts to dive in ! have a nice day!